# How to set a long string in a text view in a single line with horizontal scroll

Tags: android

actually i have keep one scrollview. Inside that scroll view I set one textview at run time I want to set text in that textview. The string which I'm going to set is some what big in length so i could not get the string in a single line and i can get my string two or three lines. My scroll view layout width size is 250px. I dont want to exceed that size...My expectation is i want to see that string within that scrollview as single line if the string is exceeds the scroll size then it should horizontally scroll in text view. I tried some functions like setting horizontal scroll to scrollview and textview but nothing is work out.
Pls help me how to solve this problem.

urs,

s.kumaran.

Comment: if possible, put the TextView outside HorizontalScrollView

Answer (score 6):

you have to use these two Xml attributes in your TextView widget:

`android:scrollHorizontally="true"`

`android:singleLine="true"`

So your xml layout must contain something like this:

```
<TextView
        android:text="Single-line text view that scrolls automatically if the text is too long to fit in the widget" 
        android:singleLine="true" 
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

you can get the correspondant method for these attributes if you are creating Your TextView with code, refer to [TextView documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) :

```
setHorizontallyScrolling(boolean)
setTransformationMethod(TransformationMethod)
setMarqueeRepeatLimit(int)
```

Comment: Right Solution, I am facing this problem , now get rid up

Answer (score 3):

try this ,,

TextView.setHorizontallyScrolling(true)
   TextView.setLines(1);

where did you add the textview..Inside scrollview we able to add only one view...

Comment: Thanks for ur immediate response but i try those two ways already but not working man.

Comment: Unfortunately not enough to get the TextView to scroll the text! See my answer for the non-intuitive solution ;)

Answer (score 2):

Take [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) and [HorizontalScrollView](http://HorizontalScrollView). Just put textview inside the HorizontalScrollView. And yes make sure to mentioned `android:singleLine="true"` inside the TextView.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with a TextView inside a table and nothing detailed here solved the fact that it wouldn't scroll horizontally (automatically, which might not be the desired effect from OP, but it's quite unclear).

While comparing some code that did work, I found out the TextView must be selected for scrolling to start:

```
TextView text_view = new TextView(context);
text_view.setLines(1);
text_view.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
text_view.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);  //  At this point the view is not scrolling!
...
text_view.setSelected(true);          //  Get scrolling to start
```

Seems crazy, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

for me, this one line in the EditText xml was enough:

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify if this was in XML or java code, but here's the java code to get that working:

```
    // Allow textView to scroll
    textView.setSingleLine(true);
    textView.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
    textView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
    textView.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
    textView.setSelected(true);
    textView.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
```

The only unnecessary item here is the padding, which I find to look best so the text does not touch the border of our 250px TextView.